# How can I run a noise simulation in LTspice for a differential input circuit?

Tags: ltspice

I designed a five transistor transconductance amplifier with single-ended output. I want to do a noise simulation and find the input-referred noise, but I’m unsure how to set this up for a circuit with differential input.

In the attached diagram, I’ve applied a common mode voltage to both inputs, but in the .noise command, I’ve only selected one input source, Vp1.

[image: 5 transistor single-ended output OTA]

Comment: I think all of the input-referred noise is conventionally lumped onto the non-inverting input node. (Drawings usually don't show a voltage noise generator on the inverting node, but do show one on the non-inverting node.) I think if you go [here](https://www.ti.com/video/series/precision-labs/ti-precision-labs-op-amps.html?keyMatch=OP%20AMPS%20NOISE) to TI's series of videos and look at the 9 video series on Noise there, you may find what you need. I'm not going to offer any expertise on this, though. Too little experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reviewed a few related questions about multiple sources for noise analysis and tried to reproduce the posters' underlying problem. What if this problem results from them misunderstanding the purpose of noise analysis? A typical scenario where you want to know the input referred noise is a noise analysis of high speed communication circuits. Input signal from a communication line is fed into a communication device represented by the circuit analyzed. You are given the noise level on the input signal and want to know if your device is fit to process ("to condition") this signal. Basically, you'd like to have the contribution of your circuit into the total noise figure to be less than (or better much less than) the noise level of the signal from the wire. Your circuit amplifies the original noise, so you should account for this amplification or better compare noise levels at the circuit input. It is where the 'input referred noise' concept come from.

I hope this explanation makes clear the stipulation given in [LTspice help](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelpXVII/LTspiceHelp/html/DotNoise.htm): '<src> is the **noiseless** input signal' (emphasis mine). The input referred noise is not a noise generated by Vp1/Vn1 sources of your circuit: these components are noiseless voltage sources. The output noise is generated by transistors/diodes/resistors, your simulation computes this figure and also re-calculates it into an 'input referred noise' figure. When used in your communication system, the noisy input signal should be fed to Vp_in/Vn_in from the other unit, from outside your circuit. To estimate the noise performance of your simulated circuit, you compare the (external) input signal noise against the 'input referred noise', which is the V(inoise) of the noise analysis (see below).

A mini-guide on noise simulation, based on [LTspice help](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelpXVII/LTspiceHelp/html/DotNoise.htm)

1. You capture your circuit as you do it for all the other analysis types (tran, ac, sweep). You include every voltage/current source you need to simulate your circuit. There is no special voltage/current source you would have to add exclusively for a noise analysis, you just assign one of the sources of your circuit to use in calculation of the input-referred voltage/current density.

For example, a differential amplifier circuit with a symmetric differential voltage source:

[image: tran]

with a gain at 1MEG of about 13.5.

2. You remove the tran analysis directive (or make its text a comment). I also "generalized" the voltage source Vsig and removed the signal amplitude and frequency parameters: first, the noise analysis is of small-signal type (input signal amplitude is unity), second, the noise analysis scans a user-defined frequency range (input signal frequency migrates to the analysis directive from the source specification) -- this modification is not necessary, you can keep the source parameters in the circuit component for later use with a tran analysis run.

You add a noise directive, like `.noise V(OUT) Vsig oct 12 1 100MEG`. Also, I added the directives `.meas total_output_refered_rms_noise INTEG V(onoise)` and `.meas total_input_refered_rms_noise INTEG V(inoise)` which integrate the noise over a specified frequency range (if not specified, over the entire range indicated in the .noise directive). You can edit .meas directives as usual, via a mouse right click.

Run the simulation:

[image: noise]

3. You add the output noise graph by clicking the output node (OUT in my circuit). You add the input-referred noise, using the other UI feature: you right-click the simulation plot window and, from the context menu, select 'Add Traces'. The dialog window appears:

[image: add-traces-to-plot]

and you select V(inoise).

As you see, there is no problem of running simulation for a circuit with differential inputs. In the .noise directive, you just indicate the input source which is used as a referral for the input-referred noise.

I'd like to add, that the input source parameters can change the circuit parameters and consequently change the noise graphs. As I've said, the AC component of the input signal is irrelevant for this type of analysis: AC amplitude need not be specified as it is a small-signal analysis and AC frequency is scanned in the .noise directive (as is the case also with the .ac analysis). Still, if you change DC value in the Vsig source, the operation point is shifted and therefore the noise graph is changed, too:

[image: noise-800mV]

Also, in the 'Add Traces' dialog window you can notice multiple components contributing into the total output noise, as the MOSFET drain current (m[1,2,3...].id), the 1/f noise (m1.1overf), etc.

[image: noise-contributors]